# How to access the dynamic tabpages values?

Tags: c#

```
        private void btnAddItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (txtBoxnum.Text != "")
                {
                    tbAddItem.TabPages.Clear();
                    int boxNum = Convert.ToInt32(txtBoxnum.Text.Trim());
                    for (int i = 0; i < boxNum; i++)
                    {
                        //------------Add tab Pages------------------------
                        TabPage dynamicTabPage = new TabPage();
                        dynamicTabPage.Name = "dynTabPage"+i;
                        dynamicTabPage.Text = "Box" + (i + 1);
                        dynamicTabPage.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                        DataGridView gd = new DataGridView();
                        gd.Name = "gdData";
                        gd.Width = 1530;
                        gd.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                        gd.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            //------------Add grid header columns--------------
                        gd.Columns.Add("slno", "SlNo");
                        gd.Columns.Add("item", "Item");
                        gd.Columns.Add("Qty", "Quantity");
                        gd.Columns.Add("Price", "Price");
                        gd.Columns[0].Width = 30;
                        gd.Columns[1].Width = 440;
                        gd.Columns[2].Width = 100;
                        gd.Columns[3].Width = 140;
                        dynamicTabPage.Controls.Add(gd);
                        this.tbAddItem.TabPages.Add(dynamicTabPage);
                        gd.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnKeystroke;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    tbAddItem.TabPages.Clear();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
```

My win form has a tab Control. On the button click event(`btnAddItem_Click`) `dynamically` add tabpages and `datagridview` to tab control. The number of TabPages depend on the number entered in the textBox boxNum.Each dynamically added tabPages hold dynamically added `datagridview`.

i want to save each `datagridview` value to `database` on the save button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{    
   foreach (Control tab in tbAddItem.Controls) 
   {
        TabPage tabPage = (TabPage)tab;
        DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)tabPage.Controls[0];
        //iterate through the DataGridView saving to the Database
        dgv...
    }
}
```

Comment: i couldnt access tab.Control property

Comment: Can you tell me the error message? I've edited my answer to be more explicit

Comment: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Controls' and no extension method 'Controls' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found